# Calculating overlap between groups

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, pivot

I have a table with two columns of interest, `item_id` and `bucket_id`.  There are a fixed number of values for `bucket_id` and I'm okay with listing them out if I need to.

Each `item_id` can appear multiple times, but each occurrence will have a separate `bucket_id` value.  For example, the `item_id` of `123` can appear twice in the table, once under `bucket_id` of `A`, once under `B`.

My goal is to determine how much overlap exists between each pair of `bucket_id` values and display it as an N-by-N matrix.

For example, consider the following small example table:

```
item_id     bucket_id
=========   ===========
111         A
111         B
111         C

222         B
222         D

333         A
333         C

444         C
```

So for this dataset, buckets `A` and `B` have one `item_id` in common, buckets `C` and `D` have no items in common, etc.

I would like to get the above table formatted into something like the following:

```
        A       B       C       D
===================================
A       2       1       2       0
B       1       2       1       1
C       2       1       3       0
D       0       1       0       1
```

In the above table, the intersect of a row and column tells you how many records exist in both `bucket_id` values.  For example, where the `A` row intersects the `C` column we have a `2`, because there are 2 records that exist in both `bucket_id` A and C.  Because the intersection of X and Y is the same as the intersection of Y and X, the above table is mirrored across the diagonal.

I imagine the query involves a `PIVOT`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it working.

Note: the actual data I'm working with has a few hundred million entries but only a dozen or so buckets.  I'd rather not join the table to itself if at all avoidable.

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to get a list of all buckets. if you already have a table `buckets` with all `bucket_id` (as PK), this part is not needed:

```
with 
  buckets (bucket_id) as
  ( select distinct bucket_id
    from table_x
  ) ,
```

Then we get all bucket couples and the count of their common items - through a self-join:

```
  couples (bucket_a, bucket_b, cnt) as 
    ( select a.bucket_id, b.bucket_id, count(*)
      from table_x a 
        join table_x b
          on  a.bucket_id <= b.bucket_id
          and a.item_id = b.item_d 
      group by a.bucket_id, b.bucket_id
    )
```

Then we can show our results:

```
select a.bucket_id      as bucket_a, 
       b.bucket_id      as bucket_b, 
       coalesce(cnt, 0) as common_items
from buckets a
  join buckets b
    on a.bucket_id <= b.bucket_id
  left join couples c
    on  a.bucket_id = c.bucket_a
    and b.bucket_id = c.bucket_b ;
```

The above will show, for your sample table:

```
bucket_a  bucket_b  common_items
================================
A         A         2
A         B         1
A         C         2
A         D         0
B         B         2
B         C         1
B         D         1
C         C         3
C         D         0
D         D         1
```

If you want the pivoted output, you'll need one more processing.

---

If the number of buckets is very low as you say, you may try this one as well:

```
with 
  buckets (bucket_id) as
  ( select distinct bucket_id
    from table_x
  ) ,
select a.bucket_id      as bucket_a, 
       b.bucket_id      as bucket_b,
       ( select count(*)
         from table_x aa
           join table_x bb
             on  aa.item_id = bb.item_d 
         where a.bucket_id = aa.bucket_id
           and b.bucket_id = bb.bucket_id
       ) as common_items
from buckets a
  join buckets b
    on a.bucket_id <= b.bucket_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad answer, because in your note you say you don't want a join. But, just in case someone wants to use a join:

```
select a.bucket_id, b.bucket_id, count(a.item_id) from mytable as a left outer join mytable as b on b.item_id=a.item_id and b.bucker_id<>a.bucket_id group by a.bucket_id, b.bucket_id order by a.bucket_id, b.bucket_id;
```

(thinking further for a solution without join in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "single pass" query that will get you the information you're after, but not in the format you wish: you'll get a single row with one column for each pair of buckets (and for each bucket individually).

```
with item_counts as
(
  select item_id
  , sum(case when bucket_id = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) is_a
  , sum(case when bucket_id = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) is_b
  , sum(case when bucket_id = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) is_c
  , sum(case when bucket_id = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) is_d
  from items
  group by item_id
) select
  sum(case when is_a > 0              then 1 end) "AA"
, sum(case when is_a > 0 and is_b > 0 then 1 end) "AB"
, sum(case when is_a > 0 and is_c > 0 then 1 end) "AC"
, sum(case when is_a > 0 and is_d > 0 then 1 end) "AD"
--
, sum(case when is_b > 0              then 1 end) "BB"
, sum(case when is_b > 0 and is_c > 0 then 1 end) "BC"
, sum(case when is_b > 0 and is_d > 0 then 1 end) "BD"
--
, sum(case when is_c > 0              then 1 end) "CC"
, sum(case when is_c > 0 and is_d > 0 then 1 end) "CD"
--
, sum(case when is_d > 0 and is_d > 0 then 1 end) "DD"
  from item_counts
;
```

(This is a brute force approach, assuming you know the buckets. For 12 buckets, you'll have 12 columns in the view, and `(12*13)/2 = 78` columns in the output. The query can be generated with a script without too much hassle. Add an `else 0` in each outer case statement if you don't like the nulls.)

Output row formatted for readability, you should recognize the upper triangle from your desired output.

```
        AA         AB         AC         AD 
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
         2          1          2            
                   BB         BC         BD
           ---------- ---------- ---------- 
                    2          1          1
                              CC         CD
                      ---------- ----------
                               3           
                                         DD
                                 ----------
                                          1
```

I say "single pass" because the plan looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |       |     1 |    52 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE      |       |     1 |    52 |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW               |       |     8 |   416 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY     |       |     8 |   128 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| ITEMS |     8 |   128 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What remains to be seen is whether that `hash group by` is sustainable - could consume rather large amounts of temporary storage...